# Convert to dataframe

Tags: python, nltk

When i run below program i could print the the frequency of words occuring how do i save this as a dataframe. how can i save the tag word and its count in dataframe

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",   \
                             tokenizer = None,    \
                             preprocessor = None, \
                             stop_words = None,   \
                             min_df = 0,          \
                             max_features = 50) 

text = ["Hello I am going to I with hello am"]

# Count
train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

# Sum up the counts of each vocabulary word
dist = np.sum(train_data_features.toarray(), axis=0)

# For each, print the vocabulary word and the number of times it 
# appears in the training set
for tag, count in zip(vocab, dist):
    print count, tag
```

Output

```
2 am
1 going
2 hello
1 to
1 with
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(list(zip(vocab,dist)),columns=['vocab', 'dist'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine vocab and dict and convert them into dataframe using pandas.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",   \
                         tokenizer = None,    \
                         preprocessor = None, \
                         stop_words = None,   \
                         min_df = 0,          \
                         max_features = 50) 

text = ["Hello I am going to I with hello am"]

# Count
train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

# Sum up the counts of each vocabulary word
dist = np.sum(train_data_features.toarray(), axis=0)

l=list(zip(vocab,dist))
df=pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['count','tag'])
```

Comment: can you also help me how to i keep only those tag words whose counts is more than 10 and also if there are any numeric tags how do i remove them?

Comment: to keep more than 10 tags `df=df['count' > 10]` . for later I would suggest you to post new question.

Comment: File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

Comment: basically only keep those words whose count/frequency is more than 10